# How to convert a text file into excel in bash or perl

Tags: excel, bash, perl

[image: sample excel sheet]I have a text file that has some data such as

```
aaaa:1.0
bbbb:1.1
cccc:1.3
```

I want to covert this into an excel sheet using bash/perl
The desired output is something like this

```
header1    header2
aaaa        1.0
bbbb        1.1
cccc        1.3
```

what i have tried so far is

```
(echo "header1;header2" ; cat a.txt) | sed 's/:/\t/g' > a.csv
```

but this does not seem to work.
also i want to export  this text file into an excel sheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833820/how-to-save-data-on-excel-xls-file-using-perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo -e "header1\theader2"; cat file | tr : '\t'    # > file.csv
header1 header2
aaaa    1.0
bbbb    1.1
cccc    1.3
```

or:

```
$ cat <(echo  "header1:header2") file | tr : '\t'     # > file.csv
header1 header2
aaaa    1.0
bbbb    1.1
cccc    1.3
```

Uncomment the `> file.csv` to actually write to a file.

Comment: thanks, that works .i want to export this into a excel sheet.how can i do that?

Comment: Just like you did in your question. Just redirect the output with `>` to a file.

Comment: i just edited the question with a sample excel sheet with proper formatting that i need..is something like this possible?

Comment: What is the difference? One empty line after the header? Add a `\n` to the `echo`part: `echo -e "header1\theader2\n" ...`